# Apache2 fails to start on UNIX server

Tags: unix, ssh, apache2

After restarting PLESK in SSH I ran into some problems with the webserver not being able to restart.

When I run

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

I get the following error

```
Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I than ran

```
/bin/netstat -lnp | grep '0.0.0.0:80'
```

which gave me

```
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  9097/apache2
```

I have no idea how to proceed from here to get things up and running again.

Edit: I killed process 9097 as suggested by Ed Heal and Chipmunk0110. After that I still couldn't start apache. I resulted in the same error. 
/bin/netstat -lnp | grep '0.0.0.0:80' now results in

```
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  21171/apache2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo kill -9 9097
```

9097 is the process id of this particular apache instance

Comment: I tried that and than tried to restart apache2 again with the same result

Comment: I ran `killall -9 apache2` and than was able to restart. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, the 9097 command did not work because by the time you ran the command the pid must have changed

Answer (score 1):

You have apache already running! Do a `ps -aux | grep apache` to find the process and kill it.

You should be then able to restart it.